# Linear Regression Model with a variable that zeroes the result

Tags: r, linear-regression

For my class we have to create a model to predict the credit balance of each individuals. Based on observations, many results are zero where the `lm` tries to calculate them.

To overcome this I created a new variable that results in zero if X and Y are true.

```r
CB$Balzero = ifelse(CB$Rating<=230 & CB$Income<90,0,1)
```

This resulted in getting 90% of the zero results right. The problem is:

How can I place this variable in the `lm` so it correctly results in zeros when the proposition is true and the calculation when it is false?

Something like: `lm=Balzero*(Balance~.)`

Answer (score 2):

I think that

```r
y ~ -1 + Balzero:Balance
```

*might* work (you haven't given us a reproducible example to try).

- `-1` tells R to omit the intercept
- `:` specifies an interaction. If both variables are numeric, then `A:B` includes the product of `A` and `B` as a term in the model.

The second term could also be specified as `I(Balzero*Balance)` (`I` means "as is", i.e. interpret `*` in the usual numerical sense, not in its formula-construction context.)

These specifications should fit the model

```
Y = beta1*Balzero*Balance + eps
```

where `eps` is an error term.

If `Balzero == 0`, the predicted value will be zero. If `Balzero==1`  the predicted value will be `beta1*Balance`.

You might want to look into **random forest** models, which naturally incorporate the kind of qualitative splitting that you're doing by hand in your example.

Comment: Thanks, Ben! I'm going to try this! I'll see if I can add reproductible! What should I add for that?